# Is it possible to pass a flash message from Rails to Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, rack, middleware

I have a project that uses Sinatra for static pages and Rails for the application.

I allow the request to hit one or the other by doing this in `config.ru`:

```
run Rack::Cascade.new([
  EightyEightTactical::Root,
  EightyEightTactical::Application
])
```

Where `EightyEightTactical::Root` is a subclass of `Sinatra::Base` and `EightyEightTactical::Application` is a subclass of `Rails::Application`.

I'm in a tricky situation where I need to set a flash message in a Rails controller and display it in a Sinatra layout.

I notice that Rails uses `ActionDispatch::Flash` in middleware, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the flash messages outside of a Rails app. Am I mistaken, or can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Cookie session store, you can do the following:

1) Access the session cookie with the name specified in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.

2) Decrypt the session cookie to get the session hash

3) Access the key called `flash` which contains a hash.

4) Iterate and display the flash message.

You should look at [ActionController::Session::CookieStore](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb) class for more details.

Comment: [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/873195) for anyone else who's interested.

Comment: I wanted to provide a code sample similar to yours for reference, but got to lazy :-).